# Adding columns in Donations with values of a custom field for GiveWP?

Tags: wordpress

I am using the GiveWP plugin to accept donations and want the donors to be able to specify who they are donating for. I have already added the field to the form using the Code Snippets plugin and the code provided in the GiveWP Documentation, and can see the information on the Donation Confirmation immediately after a successful donation.

```
    add_action( 'give_fields_after_donation_levels', function( $group ) {
    $group->append(
        give_field( 'text', 'playersName' )
            ->showInReceipt()
            ->minLength(2)
            ->label( __( 'Player\'s Name' ))
            ->maxLength(30)
            ->placeholder('Player\'s name') 
            ->storeAsDonorMeta()
            ->required()
            ->helpText( __( 'Add the name of the player that you are donating for.' ) )
    );
});



// Adds player name to donation confirmation page
function render_givewp_field_api_fields($payment_id) {
    $player_name = give_get_meta($payment_id, 'playersName', true);

    if ($player_name) {
        echo '<div id="" class="postbox">';
        echo '<h3 class="handle">' . esc_html__('Player\'s Name') . '</h3>';
        echo '<div class="inside" style="padding-bottom:10px">';
        echo esc_html($player_name);
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

add_action('give_view_donation_details_billing_after', 'render_givewp_field_api_fields', 10, 1);
```

However, I'm having trouble adding this information to the Donation information in the WP Dashboard. I need to be able to attribute each donation to who the donation was made for. I can't even see the information in the donation information when clicking on individual donations. After the function redner_givewp_field_api_fields did not add the info to the dashboard, and only to the confirmation page, I found the following online:

```
// Add column
function givewp_add_donation_column( $columns ) {
        
  // Unset Default Detail column and re-arrange it.
  unset( $columns['details'] );

        $columns['playername'] = __( 'Player', 'give' );
        $columns['details']         = __( 'Details', 'give' );

        return $columns;
    }

// This function gets the custom field data and adds it to the new column.
function givewp_column_data( $value, $payment_id, $player_name ) {

  if ( 'playername' === $player_name ) {

    //Get the custom field data
    $value = give_get_meta( $payment_id, 'playersName', true );

  }

  return $value;

}
```

This also did not add the custom field data to the Donation details in the WP Dashboard. Can anyone steer me in the right direction?